# Updating sql with html form output

Tags: mysql

Hi guys I am trying to save a form to MYSQL while taking the result and add it as a message and log it into another table.

Note the form submits fine but it insert a string into the row instead of a value.

Example -- Status has been Updated to ".$status." instead of actually posting the value.

Html form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<select name="status" onchange="this.form.submit()">

<option value="0" {if $test_array[i].STATUS == '0'}
selected{/if}>Test 1</option>
<option value="1" {if $$test_array[i].STATUS == '1'}
selected{/if}>Test 2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

and MYSQL:

```
$msg = 'Status has been Updated to ".$status."';
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".PRFX."TABLE_TEST_STATUS SET
TEST_ID =". $db->qstr( $wo_id).",
TESTR_STATUS_DATE       =". $db->qstr( time()).",
TEST_STATUS_NOTES       =". $db->qstr( $msg)."
```

How can I get the value that is posted from the html form into $msg= ".$status." ?

Thanks soo much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using have mismatched quotes and are also using the variable inside single quotes. In PHP variables inside singles quotes are not parsed.

Change you code from

```
$msg = 'Status has been Updated to ".$status."';
```

to

```
$msg = 'Status has been Updated to "' . $status . '"';
```

If you want to know more about differences between single and double quotes in PHP check my  post [PHP double quotes vs single quotes](http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-double-quotes-vs-single-quotes/) that I have on my blog.

Comment: very interesting, thanks for the suggestion but it did not work. it output Status has been Updated to ""

Comment: hey sorry, i got it working. was an error on my end. thanks so much.